# Reset form state VueJS and VueRouter

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am currently working on a step by step registration created with VueJS and VueRouter.

The basic premise of the form is that a user has to select a signup option before proceeding to enter his personal details. However, I would like the form to be reset every time a different sign up option is selected.

[VueJs + VueRouter Multi Step Form](https://codepen.io/eokorie/pen/eRYGKa)

```
/**
 *
 * @type {Vue}
 */
let page2Component = Vue.component('pageTwo', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            step1: {
                firstname: '',
                lastname: ''
            }
        }
    },
    template: `<div>
<h2>Registration</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" role="form">
        <legend>Details</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name..." v-model.trim="step1.firstname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last name..." v-model.trim="step1.lastname">
        </div>

    </form>
<div>
<router-link to="/" class="btn btn-default">Back</router-link>
<router-link to="/" class="btn btn-primary">Next Page</router-link>
</div>
</div>`,
    created: function () {

    },

    methods: {
        resetUserDetails: function() {
            this.step1.firstname = '';
            this.step1.lastname = '';
        }
    }
});

/**
 *
 * @type {Vue}
 */
let page1Component = Vue.component('pageOne', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            selectedSignUpOption: ''
        }
    },
    template: `<div>
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" role="form">
        <legend>Sign Up Options</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="signup_option" value="user" v-model.trim="selectedSignUpOption"> Register As A User
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="signup_option" value="content-editor" v-model.trim="selectedSignUpOption"> Register As A Content Editor
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    <div>
        <router-link to="/page2" class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:disabled="!signupOptionSelected">Next Page</router-link>
    </div>

</div>`,
    created: function () {

    },

    watch: {
        '$route'(to, from) {
            // react to route changes...
            // don't forget to call next()
            console.log('to: ', to);
            console.log('from: ', from);
            console.log(this);
        },

        selectedSignUpOption: function() {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.selectedSignUpOption);
        }
    },

    computed: {
        signupOptionSelected: function() {
            return this.selectedSignUpOption !== '';
        }
    }
});

/**
 *
 * @type {Vue}
 */
let wizardComponent = Vue.component('wizardForm', {
    template: `<div>
<keep-alive>
<router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
</div>`,
    created: function () {
        let children = [];
        children.push({path: '/', component: page1Component});
        children.push({path: '/page2', component: page2Component});
        router.addRoutes(children);
    }
});

/**
 * Vue App Initialisation
 */

Vue.config.devtools = true;
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

const routes = [];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for routes: routes
});

console.log('routes', routes);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    /**
     *
     */
    let vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router,
    });

});
```

I have included a link to the form that I am working on.  Any one have any idea as to how I can achieve this?  Ideally, I would like to be able to call the **resetUserDetails** method in the **page2Component** when the sign up option is different to the last one that was selected.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I am using VueJS 2 btw.

Thanks,

Emmanuel

Comment: you want to reset the form only when different option is selected or every other time when the user navigates back to options page and return to form page?

Comment: @Pradeepb I would like to reset the form only when a different option is selected.

Comment: you should pass the selectedOption value for this to work. check [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgJOEq). Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @Pradeepb that's awesome... I had actually started working a similar solution, using an event bus of sorts, but yours is a lot simpler

Comment: cool.I will add it as an answer. Accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you should pass selected value as to second component.

> your route config will look like this

```
children.push({path: '/:option/page2', component: page2Component});
```

> form component

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.option'(to, from) {
        if((this.prevSelection && this.$route.params.option) && (this.$route.params.option !== this.prevSelection)){
            this.prevSelection = this.$route.params.option
            this.resetUserDetails()
        }
    }
}
```

For more information please have a look at [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgJOEq)